# zAccordion - slider jquery and html - text on image slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a script in jquery:

```
    *<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#example14").zAccordion({
                tabWidth: "15%",
                width: "100%",
                height: "100%"
            });
            $(window).resize(function() {
                $("#example14").height($(window).height());
                $("#example14 li").height($(window).height());
                $("#example14 img").height($(window).height());
            });
        });
    </script>*
```

and some html:

```
        *<ul id="example14">
            <li><img src="images/slide0.gif" width="100%" height="100%" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/slide1.gif" width="100%" height="100%" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/slide2.gif" width="100%" height="100%" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/slide3.gif" width="100%" height="100%" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/slide4.gif" width="100%" height="100%" alt="" /></li>
        </ul>*
```

The quastion is: How can I generate some text on my image slide in CSS for example? Please help me! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked with CSS, right?

```
<ul id="example14">
    <li><img src="images/slide0.gif" width="100%" height="100%" alt="" />
        <div class="text">lorem lorem lorem</div></li>
    <li><img src="images/slide1.gif" width="100%" height="100%" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/slide2.gif" width="100%" height="100%" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/slide3.gif" width="100%" height="100%" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/slide4.gif" width="100%" height="100%" alt="" /></li>
</ul>
```

```
.text{
    position:relative;
    top:-100px;
}
```